# JWT Passport Not Returning User Data From Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

First time questioner, long time searcher. I'm having problems getting the user object to return from a Passport JWT verification call and I'm hoping someone can help figure out what's going wrong.

Here's my passport jwt configuration:

```
import jwtSecret from './jwtConfig';

const passport = require('passport'),
  localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  User = require('../sequelize'),
  JWTstrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
  ExtractJWT = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const opts = {
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT'),
      secretOrKey: jwtSecret.secret,
    };

    passport.use(
  'jwt',
  new JWTstrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    console.log('payload received');
    console.log(jwt_payload.id);
    try {
    User.findOne({
      where: {
        username: jwt_payload.id,
      },
    }).then(user => {
      console.log('user');
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        console.log('user found in db in passport');
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        console.log('user not found in db');
        return done(null, false);
      }
    });
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  }),
);
```

Here's my route where I'm calling the JWT Passport authentication:

```
import passport from 'passport';

module.exports = app => {
  app.get(
    '/findUser',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.user);
      res.status(200).send({
        user: user,
        message: 'authenticated',
      });
    },
  );
};
```

And here's my `server.js` file, where I'm instantiating the routes.

```
import express from 'express';
import Cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import logger from 'morgan';
import passport from 'passport';
const app = express();

const API_PORT = process.env.API_PORT || 3000;

require('./config/passport');

app.use(Cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(passport.initialize());

require('./routes/loginUser')(app);
require('./routes/registerUser')(app);
require('./routes/findUsers')(app);

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${API_PORT}`));

module.exports = app;
```

Maybe I'm going about using Passport JWT incorrectly, or calling it incorrectly, but each time I test it, I can see the token I'm creating, I can see user is found in the database, but it never gets returned when the `return done(null, user)` is called.

Each time I used Passport's local strategy to register and login the user and generate the JWT token with no problem, but for some reason I cannot get this user object back from Passport JWT.

Thanks for any help you can provide, I've been scouring the Internet, Github, Stack Overflow and the many blogs out there on this problem, but I haven't found a solution to my roadblock yet.

Follow up: I'm using React on the front end to make my call to server. The generated JWT token is set in local storage on the login call with the key 'JWT', it's then extracted for the next call to find the user's data like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let accessString = localStorage.getItem('JWT');
    if (accessString === null) {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        error: true,
      });
    }
    await axios
      .get('http://localhost:3003/findUser', {
        params: {
          username: this.props.match.params.username,
        },
        headers: { JWT: accessString },
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          first_name: response.data.first_name,
          last_name: response.data.last_name,
          email: response.data.email,
          username: response.data.username,
          password: response.data.password,
          isLoading: false,
          error: false,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.data);
      });
  }
```

So perhaps, I'm not passing my JWT auth header in Axios correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar setup and am calling just `done(null, user);` without `return`.

Comment: I've tried that as well without success. Thanks for trying though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Ok, disregard my earlier comment - removing the return does seem to work with returning the body - but I was only able to ascertain this through Insomnia testing of the endpoint. Which I believe, means I'm not correctly extracting the JWT with Passport. Because when I try to hit the same endpoint through my app, it returns a 401 unauthorized.

Comment: For Insomnia testing, I've got the same route `http://locahost:3003/findUser?username=test23` and auth as bearer token: <JWT token> with prefix: 'JWT'. This gives me a 200 return and the user info, but when I try to do the same thing from my app, it gives me the 401 mentioned above. Can you see anything from my previously posted code that might cause this? I know the JWT is getting stored in local storage but it doesn't seem to be getting extracted correctly.

Comment: I don't know what is your client framework/environment. You must add the JWT to request headers but that seems very obvious hint, I am sure you have done that  :) Check the network request headers whether and how the token is sent in the request. The `Authorization` header should be `JWT ${token}`, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I'm using React for the front end. The token's being stored in local storage as the key value pair of 'JWT' and the token. I'm extracting it for the call to the server like so. ```componentDidMount() {
    let accessString = localStorage.getItem('JWT');
    if (accessString === null) {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        error: true,
      });
    }
    await axios
      .get('http://localhost:3003/findUser', {
        params: {
          username: this.props.match.params.username,
        },
        headers: { JWT: accessString },
      })```

Comment: Can you add that to question? This is unreadable. Still, have you checked network tab of devtools for request headers? Oh, and I have never used React :)

Comment: Ah, from what I see, the header is not OK. You are creating header as `JWT: ${token}`, it should be `Authorization: 'JWT ' + accessString`. Mind the space after JWT.

Comment: Bless you, that worked. Thank you so much for your help, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it!